# Meaning of song lyrics

Tags: translation

These are lyrics to a song sung by a brother and sister who have suffered a difficult childhood.

> 今日までずっと
>   Until today
>
> どんな時も
>   No matter what
>
> 二人で   生きてきた
>   We are two people who lived (?)
>
> 俺が凍えたら…
>   If I was freezing …
>
> 抱きしめてくれた
>   You hugged me tightly
>
> 私がひもじい時
>   When I was hungry
>
> 慰めてくれた
>   You comforted me
>
> いつも   きれいだった
>   It was always lovely (?)
>
> いつも   バカばかり
>   Always just fools (??)
>
> 肩寄せ合い   泣き明かした夜
>   Crying all night in each other’s arms
>
> 何があっても
>   In spite of everything
>
> 手をとり
>   You took my hand
>
> 分かち合い
>   Sharing
>
> 魂   近く
>   A closeness in spirit (?)
>
> 生きた
>   We lived
>
> いつも   二人…
>   Always, the two of us

I think I get most of it (corrections are most welcome), but I’m really uncertain about the following parts:

> 二人で   生きてきた
>   We are two people who lived (?) – as in survived?
>
> いつも   きれいだった
>   It was always lovely (?) – is this an appropriate use for きれい?
>
> いつも   バカばかり
>   Always just fools (??) – totally stumped here!
>
> 魂   近く
>   A closeness in spirit (?) – and here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 二人で 生きてきた We were living together
>
> いつも きれいだった you were always lovely

from the context, I agree to the word `lovely`

> いつも バカばかり You always make (made) me laugh

`バカばかり` means more like you do something stupid, acting funny or you do things excessively. It depends on the context. I'd go for the laugh...

> 魂 近く our spirits were close together
>
> 生きた and lived

I think `魂 近く　生きた` is one sentence.